# How can I upgrade my weapon to be un-damageable?

Tags: weapons, dark-heresy-1e

So I have (or unfortunately "had") an Omnissiah Axe.

In our last game, we came across what we perceived to be a Necron Pariah. During the battle, it completely destroyed my axe through the use of some form of "acid" (though meta-game knowledge pointed to something similar to scarabs).

In the Dark Heresy rules, once I repair/replace my axe, is there any way I can upgrade it in an attempt to avoid this happening again?

The only other thing I found was the Lathe Blade upgrade (DH: Inquistors HB p.147), though that only talks about increasing the physical quality of the weapon, so I'm not sure how useful that would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**RAW** speaking **no**, there is no rule about making thing *un-damageable*, but with the right Trade **you could try** to mix your Omnimessiah Axe with a Force-field (%chance of avoid taking damage). Or, crazy thing, mix it with Stasis-field. With the approval of your GM of course.

Since the Omnimessiah Axe have the power field attribute, it can't be broken by the power field effect.

Increasing physical quality with Lathe Blade only increases its efficiency, no word in RAW about improving the weapon's sturdiness. And Lathes Blade works **only on primitive weapons** anyway.

PS: By wearing a Force-field you would also be able to avoid damage.